# print doesn't work while iterations are going inside foreach loop

Tags: perl, foreach, perl-module, progress, buffering

I try to find a way to print a progressbar on the commandline while parsing logfiles. Get logfiles=> foreach file => foreach line {do}.

The idea: I want to print a part of the progressbar in every "foreach file" loop. Meaing: print the whole bar if you just parse 1 file. print half of the bar for every file when u parse 2 files and so on. You find the specific code at the bottom.

The problem: The output (print "*") is printed after ALL foreach iteration are done - not in between. Details are in the Code.

Does someone have an idea how to print inside a foreach? Or can tell me the problem? I don't get it :(.

```
my @logfiles=glob($logpath);

print "<------------------>\n";
$vari=20/(scalar @logfiles);

foreach my $logfile (@logfiles){
    open(LOGFILEhandle, $logfile);
    @lines = <LOGFILEhandle>;

    print "*" x $vari;   #won't work, only after loop. Even a "print "*";" doesn't work

    foreach my $line (@lines){
        #print "*"; works "in between". print "*" x $vari; does not.

        if ($line=~/xyz/){
            ......
            ......
        }
    close(LOGFILEhandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `print "*" x $vari, "\n";` or set `$|=1`. Perhaps you're [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering. The output is buffered until a certain amount is reached or you print a newline. To change this behaviour simply add

```
$| = 1 ;
```

at the top of your file. This will turn on autoflush for `STDOUT`.
There is more than one way to do it and a little bit longer and less cryptic is Borodins suggestion:

```
STDOUT->autoflush();
```

Comment: `STDOUT->autoflush` is much more self-explanatory and can be used on any given file handle.

Comment: "suffering from buffering" sounds like a common problem :). 5 chars made it work. thanks!

Comment: @Borodin Yes you are right ... I added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest [Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar) module to avoid reinventing the wheel.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ProgressBar;

my @files = qw (file1 file2 file3 file4); 

my $progress = Term::ProgressBar->new(scalar @files);

for (0..@files) {
  $| = 1;
  sleep(1); #introducing sleep for demo purpose otherwise bar will fill up quickly
  #open the file, do some operations and when you are done
  #update the bar
  $progress->update($_);
}
```